# How can I pass argument to already running java program

Tags: java, swing

I want to run only a single instance of my program with arguments and I have done that successfully. When I run a second instance with arguments, it doesn't execute and closes because the previous instance is running. However, I have to pass arguments each time, so how can I pass the argument to the original instance which is in running state. I have to pass arguments like this: `java -jar JARFILE.jar 123456`

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

static JFrame jf;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        RuntimeMXBean rt = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        final int runtimePid = Integer.parseInt(rt.getName().substring(0, 
         rt.getName().indexOf("@")));

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // If exists another instance, show message and terminates the current instance.
                    // Otherwise starts application.
                    if (getMonitoredVMs(runtimePid)) {
                        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
                        mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        mf.setSize(400, 400);
                        mf.setTitle(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        mf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        mf.setVisible(true);
                    } else {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is another instance of this application running.");
                    }
                } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private static boolean getMonitoredVMs(int processPid) throws URISyntaxException {
        MonitoredHost host;
        Set vms;
        try {
            host = MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost(new HostIdentifier((String) null));
            vms = host.activeVms();
        } catch (MonitorException mx) {
            throw new InternalError(mx.getMessage());
        }
        MonitoredVm mvm = null;
        String processName = null;
        try {
            mvm = host.getMonitoredVm(new VmIdentifier(String.valueOf(processPid)));
            processName = MonitoredVmUtil.commandLine(mvm);
            processName = processName.substring(processName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, processName.length());
            mvm.detach();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Object vmid : vms) {
            if (vmid instanceof Integer) {
                int pid = ((Integer) vmid).intValue();
                String name = vmid.toString(); // default to pid if name not available  
                try {
                    mvm = host.getMonitoredVm(new VmIdentifier(name));
                    // use the command line as the display name  
                    name = MonitoredVmUtil.commandLine(mvm);
                    name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, name.length());
                    mvm.detach();
                    if ((name.equalsIgnoreCase(processName)) && (processPid != pid)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    // ignore  
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Command line arguments are given on startup and cannot be changed on runtime from external. I can't imagine why this would make sense anyways. A regular application uses the startup arguments to control what / how to start. If it's already running, you should not need them anymore.The problem with your code is, that you check if the program is running by using some stuff I don't know. Why don't you write a PID file like many other services do?

Comment: What arguments do you want to pass ? Also please post [mcve]. No need for all this code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Where are you even using the arguments? I don't see usage of `args`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved my problem using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct pre-implemented way to do this.  What most programs do is allow a "New" instance but then search for the "Original" instance and somehow pass the parameters.  Both of those problems--finding the existing task and passing the parameters-- are not solved, you can pick your implementation.

One way is to have the first instance started create a file (Perhaps a file containing it's PID).   The second process might look for that file, find it and write the new value to it then exit.  Your first one would have to watch the file for updates and read the new value.

Another method is to open a fixed port when you start.  If you can't open the port, assume there is an instance already running, connect to the port and send the new parameters.

Comment: Depends on if you have a GUI and if it's active and if it's running as a service and ...,  You are right, if a GUI is available, why not just allow it as an editable field, but if not, opening a port and listening for messages/sending messages is pretty close to trivial once you've done it a few times.

Comment: He does have a GUI, but come to find out, his code doesn't even make use of `args`, so I deleted my comments as I'm starting to believe what he thinks he may want isn't really what he wants.